# How do you use fixtures with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures, minitest, attr-encrypted

I want to test a model that uses [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) to encrypt a secret in the database

```
class Thing
  attr_encrypted :secret, encode: true
end
```

But when I define the secret in a fixture the encoded newline character gets escaped out.

```
one:
  encrypted_secret: '<%= Thing.encrypt_secret(SecureRandom.uuid) %>'
```

That is:

```
'axZFZEknxUSYdUlPhwLBbj8CwSeCW5at2INA98EcCcY7MVFdmXvk7Sb4DZhC\nm6qD\n'
```

Is stored in the database as:

```
'axZFZEknxUSYdUlPhwLBbj8CwSeCW5at2INA98EcCcY7MVFdmXvk7Sb4DZhC
 m6qD'
```

The problem with this is that this then fails:

```
thing = things(:one)
assert_equal thing, Thing.find_by_secret(thing.secret)
```

Thing.find_by_secret(thing.secret) returns nil because the resulting SQL query tries to match the two versions of the encryped secret and fails to get a match.

I have tried:

```
one:
  encrypted_secret: 'axZFZEknxUSYdUlPhwLBbj8CwSeCW5at2INA98EcCcY7MVFdmXvk7Sb4DZhC\nm6qD\n'
```

but get the same result.

How can I configure my fixtures to work with attr_encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works is to replace all '\n' with '\\n' and use double quotes. This works:

```
one:
  encryped_secret: "<%= Thing.encrypt_secret(SecureRandom.uuid).gsub(/\n/, '\\\\n') %>"
```

Is there a tidier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation under Rails4 + attr_encrypted + fixture + Minitest environment, and here my workaround is.

In summary, I had the following steps:

1. write plain (= unencrypted) text fixture with a specific file extention (in my case, it is *.yml.noenc).
2. write rake-task to convert from the plain fixture (*.yml.noenc) to encrypted fixture (*.yml).

Let me explain the detail below.

For example, "Message" model has two attributes 'name' and 'body' which are required to be encrypted as follows:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :name, key: ...
  attr_encrypted :body, key: ...
  ...
end
```

1. write test/fixtures/messages.yml.noenc as follows, which has plain name and body text:

> ```
> msg1:
>   name: Hello
>   body: Hello, I am here...
> msg2:
>   name: How are you
>   body: Good morning, ...
> ```

2. write like the following rake-task (e.g. lib/tasks/encrypt_fixture.rake) to convert messages.yml.noenc to messages.yml:

> ```
> require 'active_record/fixtures'
>
> src_yml   = 'test/fixtures/messages.yml.noenc'
> dest_yml  = 'test/fixtures/messages.yml'
>
> task 'test'   => dest_yml
>
> namespace :[MY_APP] do
>   desc "generate encrypted fixture"
>   file dest_yml => src_yml do |t|
>     require Rails.root + 'config/environment'
>
>     encrypted_hash  = {}
>     for k, v in YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root + src_yml)).result) do
>       msg = Message.new(v.merge([ANY ADDITIONAL ATTRS]))
>       encrypted_hash[k] = {
>         'encrypted_name'    => msg.encrypted_name,
>         'encrypted_name_iv' => msg.encrypted_name_iv,
>         'encrypted_body'    => msg.encrypted_body,
>         'encrypted_body_iv' => msg.encrypted_body_iv,
>         [ANY ADDITIONAL KEY_N_VALUE]
>       }
>     end
>
>     File.open(Rails.root + t.name, 'w') do |f|
>       f.write(<<EOH)
>     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
>     # DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE!!
>     #
>     # This file is generated from #{src_yml} by:
>     #
>     #   (edit #{src_yml})
>     #   $ rake [MY_APP]:generate_fixture, or
>     #   $ rake
>     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
> EOH
>       f.write(encrypted_hash.to_yaml)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

Please substitute [MY_APP], [ANY ADDITIONAL ATTRS], and [ANY ADDITIONAL KEY_N_VALUE] to actual values.

Then, 'rake' or 'rake test' checks file dependency between messages.yml.noenc and messages.yml, and generate messages.yml when necessary before 'rake test'.